# WebFlux WebFilter get Multipart Form Data - Allways empty - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a Java 11, Spring Boot 2.7.16 Only with Webflux and Netty (Without starter web i.e without tomcat) application.

I'm trying to get the multipart form data in a WebFilter and post it to an application.

**NO. I cannot build a controller with @RequestPart. This is a requirement of my solution.**

The problem is that `ServerWebExchange.getFormData()` or `ServerWebExchange.getMultipartData()` is allways empty, even sending a request with multipart form...

The code:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebInterceptor implements WebFilter {

    private final SecurityService securityService;
    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {


        if(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getContentType().isCompatibleWith(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)){
       

            var token = securityService.doSomeThing(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get("Authorization").get(0));

// Don't print nothing
            exchange.getMultipartData()
                    .doOnNext(data -> System.out.println(data.toSingleValueMap()));

// Don't print nothing
            exchange.getFormData()
                    .doOnNext(data -> System.out.println(data.toSingleValueMap()));

          
// Never post :/
            exchange.getMultipartData().subscribe(value -> {

                webClient.post()
                        .uri(URI.create(token.getUrl() + "?" +  exchange.getRequest().getURI()  ))
                        .headers(headers -> headers.setAll(token.getHeaders(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getContentType().toString())))
                        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(value))
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
            });

            return Mono.empty();

        }else return chain.filter(exchange);

    }
}
```

This is the request:

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url 'localhost:8080/uri' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  --form 'arquivo=@/home/me/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot from 2023-10-10 08-37-37.png'
```

The documentation says:

- `ServerWebExchange.getMultipartData()` returns value if content-type is multipart-form or empty otherwise.
- `ServerWebExchange.getFormData()` returs value if content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded or empty otherwise.

What's the problem? Why both `ServerWebExchange.getFormData()` or `ServerWebExchange.getMultipartData()` is allways empty?

Comment: It isn't empty, you aren't subscribing to the mono tha tis being returned effectifly making it do, nothing. Your code is simply wrong. You are writing reactive code with an imperative mindset.

Comment: @M.Deinum what about the   `exchange.getMultipartData().subscribe()` snippet? Even using `subscribe` function I still not subscribing?

Comment: It is but you aren't subscribing the `WebClient` call, making it again effectivly do nothing.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'll be glad if you could provide an example in an answer on this question. I don't get the "you aren't subscribing the web client" part.

Comment: The last method in your `subscribe` is `.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)` which returns a `Flux`. This is a reactive type and it doesn't do anything until you `subscribe()` to it. So while you have a subscribe method effectively the code you call in there doesn't do anything.